# how to bind key code to submit button in IE mobile

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, key, bind

I am developing application for IE mobile and i want to bind function to some keys on the keyboard.

for example:

I would like to have this button clicked when i press for example ENTER key (keycode == 13)

Is there any way to do it? I tried with keyup and keydown but id doesn't work

EDIT:

```
 document.onkeydown = function(e){
         var n = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
            if(n==9) document.getElementById("submit_button").click(); //alert("tab");
        }
```

this code works on other browsers, but i need it to work on IE mobile

PS: i need it to keycode 9 (Tab button)

Comment: Could you please put the code that you tried up here?

Comment: Some things to try quickly: fire off an alert with n's value every time the key is pressed to check to make sure you have the right code.  Also, if you are actually trying to get a form to submit, you might want to target the form and send the `submit` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
<head>
<script>
  function check(){
            if(event.keyCode == 9){
              document.getElementById("submit_button").click();  
            }
        }
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="check();"></body>
```